# The correct way of using useReducer to handle open/close of multiple dialogs in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am using `useReducer` in a functional React component that has multiple dialogs.

It renders like:

```
return (
    <div className="container">

        { /* All Dialogs go here */ }
        <AddProfileDialog open={isOpen.ADD_PROFILE} />
        <EditProfileDialog open={isOpen.EDIT_PROFILE} />
    </div>
)
```

And I am using hooks to handle internal states in this component.

My `userReducer` looks like

```
const [isOpen, dispatch] = useReducer((state, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'ADD_PROFILE':
                return { ...state, ADD_PROFILE: true }
            case 'EDIT_PROFILE':
                return { ...state, EDIT_PROFILE: false }
            default:
                return state
        }
    }, [])
```

First of all, I am not sure if this is the right way to handle the status of multiple dialogs.

Also, is there a way to reset the state of all other dialogs in this component to default state (all `false`) except for the selected one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this and You can add a cancel action.

```
const [isOpen, dispatch] = useReducer((state, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'ADD_PROFILE':
                return { ...state, ADD_PROFILE: true, EDIT_PROFILE: false }
            case 'EDIT_PROFILE':
                return { ...state, EDIT_PROFILE: false, ADD_PROFILE: false }
            case 'CANCEL':
                return {...state, EDIT_PROFILE: false, ADD_PROFILE: false }
            default:
                return state
        }
    }, [])
```

Comment: What if I add more modals? Wouldn't it become super long?

Comment: Due to the nature of redux, you are returning a new state tree every time you're dispatching an action. If you want more modals you have to specify it from the new state in order to actually update them specifically with a new value. Or else it doesn't know what to update.

Answer (score 0):

I think useReducer and useState both work in your situation. but useState might be easier here. There is no complex logic or sideEffect involved, we don't have to utilize useReducer here.

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState({ADD_PROFILE:false,EDIT_PROFILE:false});

setOpen({...open, ADD_PROFILE:!open.ADD_PROFILE})

<div>
  < AddProfileDialog open={open.ADD_PROFILE}/>
  < EditProfileDialog open={open.EDIT_PROFILE}/>
</div>
```

However, both useReducer and useState will cause the state change, every time we open a new Dialog, all the Opened dialogs will still reRender. You may want to use React.memo is your child component is too complex.

Comment: What if I add more modals? This won't scale.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about the scale you talk about? Do you mean you will have too many state entries ? or too many Modal components? which part about the scale is your concern?

Comment: I was talking about having too many Modal components will lead to too many state entries. Is that inevitable?

Comment: I think it depends on how similar your Modal components are. you could combine those components with the same logic, pass the props, and run some logic in Modal component so that you can have less component. but you still need to manage the state inside the child component.